User gets blocked after first login every time
We have Admin Tools installed but we have white listed our IP address.
Every time my colleague logs in he is automatically blocked.
We don't see his IP address in Admin Tools, but it is white listed anyway.
What else could cause this?
User registration is automatic, he doesn't need to click a link.
I found an old question that I have written where it was the Lightspeed cache plugin but I have disabled that now.

I experienced that same behavior when working on a clients' website. I created my own Super User account in the database via phpMyAdmin. I was able to login into the back-end but immediately my account got blocked.
Admin Tools only allows login for user accounts that have been created via the User Manager.
Could you try creating a new account through Joomla's User Manager and see if that resolves the problem?

It was created by the user manager.
